# How to find the curve tangent to $y = 2x + 3$ at $x = 6$.

Tags: calculus

[image]
I don't if it is possible, but how to find the curve tangent?

Comment: Answer: y=2x+3.

Comment: I think you are misreading the question. It is not asking you  to find a "curve tangent"; it is asking you to find a curve that is tangent to $y=2x+3$ at $x=6$ (there are many such curves; you only have to find one).

Comment: Let $A=(12,12)$ and $r=3\sqrt5$ : The circle with center $A$ and radius $r$ is tangent to the line at $(6,15)$.

Answer (score 2):

Ah I am now assuming that you do not need a straight line but rather to find a curve that has as a tangent at $x=6$ the line
$$(t): y=2x+3$$
that has at $x=6$ a slope of
$$m=2$$

**Step 1:** Using line $(t)$ we find the point if tangency to be
$$A(6,15)$$

**Step 2:** We decide what type of curve we need, a parabola is the easiest to find. More than one parabola is possible, we choose to have the leading coefficient to be $1$. The curve is
$$f(x)= x^2+bx+c$$
and has a derivative
$$f’(x)=2x+b$$

**Step 3:** Noticing that the curve has to pass through $A$ i.e.
$$f(6)=15$$
$$\Rightarrow 15=(6)^2+b(6)+c$$

and has the derivative at $x=6$ equal to the slope i.e.
$$f’(6)=2$$
$$\Rightarrow 2=2(6)+b$$

We get the system of equation
$$\begin{cases}
6b+c=-21\\
b=-10
\end{cases}$$
**Step 4:** we solve the system of equation to get
$$b=-10\text{ and } c=39$$

So the curve in question becomes
$$f(x)= x^2-10x+49$$

Note that is not the only possible curve but just one of them.

Comment: I think c should be 39 since plugging in x = 6 gives 25 for your equation.

Comment: @FatsoBoo yup! Fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If a curve $y=f(x)$ is tangent to the line $y=2x+3$ at $(6,15)$ then obviously $f(x)$ must satisfy the following conditions:

1. $f(6)=15$
2. $f'(6)=2$

For example, the parabola $y=x^2-10x+39$ satisfies these conditions. So this is one answer to your question. But there are infinitely many answers.

Another one is the cubic curve: $y=x^3-106x+435$.

If you want fancy curves, this is for you: $y=\ln x-\ln6 +\frac{3}{2}x+12$.

I hope that I did not do any miscalculation as som of these friends.

Comment: You mean $y=\ln x-\ln 6+\frac32 x+12$.

Comment: Thanks...  @TonyK

Comment: How is that an elliptic curve?

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There is no "the" or "unique" curve whose tangent at a point P is a given line T. Many curves can be co-tangential at the given point.

There are many curves $ y=f(x)$ at point P $ (x=6, y=15)$
satisfying or having same or common slope/gradient $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2$.

They can touch and go up (2), touch and go down (1) keeping to one side of tangent or, touch on either side while transitioning (3) as at an inflection point T.